# Бесконечные сообщения InputMismatchException при добавлении переменных в List в бесконечном цикле

Tags: java

Всем привет. Осваиваю обработку исключений в java. Есть `ArrayList`, который в бесконечном цикле принимает на вход от пользователя числа, которые добавляются в `ArrayList`. Хочу поймать исключение, чтобы при вводе не `int` значений цикл не прекращался, а просто выводилось сообщение `"Only ints!"`, после чего пользователь мог продолжить вводить числа.
Но по факту когда вводишь не `int`, начинается бесконечный вывод сообщения. Думал, `continue` эту проблему исправит, но почему-то не работает. Подскажите, почему так и как это исправить?

```
public class Exceptions3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true){
            try{
                list.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Only ints!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда сканер при попытке выполнить `nextInt()` обнаруживает, что во входном потоке не число, он генерирует исключение и **не счситывает** это не-число из входного потока. В результате при следующей попытке считать число сканер будет **повторно** пытаться считать **то же самое не-число** и снова сгенерирует исключение. Чтобы сканер наплевал на то, чего он не может распознать, и перешел к следующему элементу входного потока, нужно при обработке исключения (в блоке `catch`) дополнительно поставить `scaner.next();`.

А `continue` в вашем примере вообще ни на что не влияет. Оно просто передаёт управление на начало цикла, куда выполнение и так перейдет после завершения блока `catch`. `continue` надо использовать тогда, когда после него в теле цикла есть еще что-то, что надо пропустить.